# Angular4 NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays error

Tags: angular, ngfor

### I have a model:

```
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  members = [];
  constructor(private responseMembers:LobsterService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.responseMembers.getMembers().subscribe(responseMembers => 
      this.members = responseMembers.members);
  }
}
```

### My service:

```
@Injectable()

export class LobsterService {
  constructor(private http:Http) {

  }

  private url:string = "http://localhost:4200/assets/data.json";
  getMembers() {
    return this.http.get(this.url).map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
```

### And then in my component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  members = [];
  constructor(private responseMembers:LobsterService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.responseMembers.getMembers().subscribe(responseMembers => 
      this.members = responseMembers.members);
  }
}
```

### App HTML ##

```
<h1>

    <h3>Organization: {{members.organization}}</h3>
    <h4>Organization Location: {{members.location}}</h4>

    <ul *ngFor="let member of members">
        <li>{{member}}</li>
    </ul>
</h1>
```

### My Json:

```
{
   "organization":"Lobster",
   "location":"Austin",
   "teams":[
      {
         "team":"Lobster Tech",
         "location":"Amsterdam",
         "members":[
            {
               "name":"Ben Samuel",
               "age":29,
               "imageUrl":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/30.jpg"
            },
            {
               "name":"Ana James",
               "age":39,
               "imageUrl":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/68.jpg"
            },
            {
               "name":"Edward Finn",
               "age":23,
               "imageUrl":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/83.jpg"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "team":"Lobster Ink",
         "location":"Cape Town",
         "members":[
            {
               "name":"Sam Jones",
               "age":49,
               "imageUrl":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/30.jpg"
            },
            {
               "name":"Helen Anthony",
               "age":26,
               "imageUrl":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/48.jpg"
            },
            {
               "name":"Gregg Best",
               "age":21,
               "imageUrl":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/23.jpg"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

This throws me error Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

What am I doing wrong? I simply would like to iterate over teams properties and also access it's children and their properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like members is an object.

You should iterate through your teams, then through your members

```
<h1>
    <h3>Organization: {{members.organization}}</h3>
    <h4>Organization Location: {{members.location}}</h4>

    <span *ngFor="let team of members.teams">
        <ul *ngFor="let member of team.members">
            <li>{{member}}</li>
        </ul>
    </span>
</h1>
```

Comment: hi, But how can we get only one team to be displayed through this?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON doesn't return members. The JSON returns an organization. An organization has teams and each team has members. If you want the service function to return all members in every team for the organization than you should be adding that post-processing logic in the map() function to translate the raw JSON response to what you expect. The map() function being called in the service allows you to easily mutate/convert the raw response to what you expect in the domain then pass that value on to the subscribe callback defined in the component. You should also consider creating a member model and mapping the raw data to that interface within the map function of the service function.